# How to get a high-quality image from an IIIFv21 API in Python?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, iiif

I have an `info.json` file in the IIIFv21 format, and I want to use it to retrieve high-quality image tiles. We can use, for example, the file that is available [here](https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979482/info.json) and looked like:

```
> {
  "@context" : "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
  "@id" : "https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979482",
  "protocol" : "http://iiif.io/api/image",
  "width" : 5414,
  "height" : 3763,
  "sizes" : [ {
    "width" : 84,
    "height" : 58
  }, {
    "width" : 169,
    "height" : 117
  }, {
    "width" : 338,
    "height" : 235
  }, {
    "width" : 676,
    "height" : 470
  }, {
    "width" : 1353,
    "height" : 940
  }, {
    "width" : 2707,
    "height" : 1881
  } ],
  "tiles" : [ {
    "width" : 1024,
    "height" : 1024,
    "scaleFactors" : [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 ]
  } ],
  "profile" : [ "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level1.json", {
    "formats" : [ "jpg" ],
    "qualities" : [ "native", "color", "gray", "bitonal" ],
    "supports" : [ "regionByPct", "regionSquare", "sizeByForcedWh", "sizeByWh", "sizeAboveFull", "rotationBy90s", "mirroring" ],
    "maxWidth" : 526,
    "maxHeight" : 526,
    "maxArea" : 111111
  } ],
  "rights" : "http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/library/items-terms-of-use/Pages/nli-copying-prohibited.aspx"
}
```

I have been trying to follow the [IIIF specification](https://iiif.io/api/image/2.1/), but I'm struggling to retrieve any tile. I've tried a few different approaches, but they haven't been successful.

Some of my attempts are:

1. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0,0,1024,1024/1024,/0/default.jpg
2. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0,0,1024,1024/1024,1024/0/default.jpg
3. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0,0/1024,1024/0/default.jpg
4. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0/0,0,1024,1024/1024,/0/default.jpg
5. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0/0,0,1024,1024/1024,1024/0/default.jpg
6. https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979451/0/0,0/1024,1024/0/default.jpg

You can change the values in the `1024`s to match the desired tile location, but this is the top left tile.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

When you use image ID `FL58252370` in a valid URL - for example:

https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL202979482/full/max/0/default.jpg

Then you get "unauthorized" as your response:

```xml
<error>
    <parameter>unauthorized</parameter>
    <text>
        Error, no permissions, please contact administrator
    </text>
</error>
```

You simply do not have access to that specific image.

(Or, maybe that is not a valid image ID. But the fact that you can retrieve the `info.json` response suggests it should be a valid image ID.)

If you replace that image ID with the ID of a valid, publicly accessible image...

```
FL58252370
```

...then the above URL will work:

https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL58252370/full/max/0/default.jpg

You can take this new ID and use it in your 6 attempts to see which URLs are valid (some of them are; some others are not).

---

The web site provides detailed guidance [here](https://www.nli.org.il/en/research-and-teach/open-library/image-api), showing how to construct a valid image URL.

If you believe you *should* have access to the image for `FL58252370`, then I guess you need to contact the NLI.